# typescript undefined variable fundamental

Tags: javascript, typescript, tslint

Recently moved from C# to TypeScript. Below code works fine and no errors. However I suspect I have not understood some TS fundamental since we just define interfaces and use them like objects/classes. What is the correct way to declare a variable of a type that is defined in an interface and then assign that variable to its own typed object.

```
let tempCompany = Company|undefined; 
// I get error if I remove undefined in above line.
// Company is an interface with many properties
tempCompany = this.someArrayOfCompanies.find(x => x.zipCode === 65432);
if (tempCompany !== undefined) { 
    // error if I do not do this if check in above line
    console.log(tempCompany.SalesFigure);
}
```

Update: Possible answer based on feedback below.
For newbies like me moving to TS from .Net/C# the confusion arises because in C# we name interfaces like IAnimal() and then have a class called Dog that implements IAnimal(). In TS we have the Animal interface (without the I) which is named so for TS intellisense to work in vs code. Additional when you api get in Angular it returns a observable list of type Animal. Basically TS is better than JS but still there is all this crazy stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this small example will clear things up for you.

```
interface Animal {
    legs: number;
}

var dog: Dog = { legs: 4 };

type canine = typeof dog;
```

Comment: legs = 4 . What if the Animal interface had lots of properties and not just one called legs ? Initializing a variable to dummy values just to get one instance of it ?

Comment: you can make variables optional in interfaces, like this, interface Animal { legs: number, hasTail?: boolean}. You do not have to initialize the hasTail variable, since it is optional.

Comment: If I have no methods like classes do then in TS I have a choice of creating an interface or creating a class. Now I need a variable or instance of this type. In a class I understand new will do it. I did not realize we have to do all this jugglery with interfaces.

Comment: Use classes then. Interfaces are for special occasions, aka. class X could inherit interfaces A, B and C and (class X implements A, B, C) and then class Y has a function "public doStuffWithB( _b: B )" and you can pass along any class that implements B. If you do not need to slice and separate functionality like this, then I just use plain classes for those cases, without interfaces.

Comment: Yes. I think I finally know. Will add an update to my question.

Comment: For your comment, I name all my interfaces startin with an I, like IAnimal, enums are singular, without a suffix (AnimalType.DOG). Just for this example, I was using non I-prefixed interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

Define a variable of type Company like this:

```
let tempCompany: Company;
```

Assigning object, what you have would work, as long as the object aligns to the interface:

```
tempCompany = this.someArrayOfCompanies.find(x => x.zipCode === 65432);
```

Comment: No. I get this [ts]
Type 'Company| undefined' is not assignable to type 'Company'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Company'. If I put the | (pipe) undefined as in my question error goes away.

Comment: that is when you assign the value? console log the value you are trying to assign and see what it looks like...if that value is not according to the interface, you'll get error..

Comment: What type is `this.someArrayOfCompanies`?

Comment: type is Company []